# Probability of $-\frac{1}{4}\leq \sin (a x)\leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: probability, trigonometry, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, geometric-probability

We know that probability of having $ \sin (a x)>0$ for a random $x$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Can we say something about the probability of the following condition?
$$-\frac{1}{4}\leq \sin (a x)\leq \frac{1}{2}$$

**Here, $a$ and $x$ are continuous and $x>0$ and $a>0$.**

Comment: $X$ follows what distribution?

Comment: probability distribution

Comment: I suppose $X$ is a random variable, which is conventionally written in capital letters.  I suggest you to [wiki probit distrib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) to c wt it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function
$$x\mapsto\sin(a x)\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)$$
is periodic with period $T:={2\pi\over a}$. When we assume that $x$ is uniformly distributed modulo $T$ then we may assume as well that $a=1$, and that $x$ is uniformly distributed modulo $2\pi$.

Draw the sin curve in the $x$-interval $[0,2\pi]$ representing a full period, and measure the total length $L$ of the subintervals where $-{1\over4}<\sin x<{1\over2}$. The probability $p$ you are after then is ${L\over2\pi}$. In this way you obtain
$$p={L\over2\pi}={2\arcsin{1\over2}+2\arcsin{1\over4}\over2\pi}=0.247097\ .$$